# Modeling hierarchical data using enums in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have multiple clients returning same data to me in different formats, for which I want to write an abstraction.

```
Client A: { 
    Category_A1:
        Sub_Category_A1_1,
        Sub_Category_A1_2

    Category_B1:
        Sub_Category_B1_1,
        Sub_Category_B1_2
}

Client B: { 
    Category_A2:
        Sub_Category_A2_1,
        Sub_Category_A2_2

    Category_B2:
        Sub_Category_B2_1,
        Sub_Category_B2_2
}
```

Here both clients A and B are returning the same categories 'A' and 'B', but are using different strings in their response.

I want abstractions Category_A and Category_B such that Category_A1, Category_A2 would map to Category_A and Category_B1, Category_B2 would map to Category_B.

The same is applicable to Sub_Categories as well - A category can only have a specific list of sub categories associated to it. I want to abstract the sub-categories as well while keeping the information that which category it belongs to.

I thought of using enums for mapping multiple categories to one:

```
public enum MyCategory {

MY_CATEGORY_A(new String[]{ CATEGORY_A1, CATEGORY_A2 }),

MY_CATEGORY_B(new String[]{ CATEGORY_B1, CATEGORY_B2 });

private String[] categories;

Category(String[] categories) {
   this.categories = categories;
}

public MyCategory getMyCategoryFromExternalCategory(final String externalCategory) {
}
};
```

What I'm finding difficult is mapping subcategories the same way while maintaining association between the category and the list of its subcategories.

What could be a clean way for achieving this using enums - as I do not have state or any other information related to categories and subcategories I do not want to use explicit classes for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you need something like Map<\Category, List<\SubCategory>>, where Category is an enum taking Category_A, Category_B.

```
public enum Category {
   CATEGORY_A, CATEGORY_B
}
```

And SubCategory would just be another object to keep track of Sub-categories

Answer (score 0):

it should work for u.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

public enum Category {


MY_CATEGORY_A(new String[]{ "CATEGORY_A1", "CATEGORY_A2" }),

MY_CATEGORY_B(new String[]{ "CATEGORY_B1", "CATEGORY_B2" });

private final String[] categories;

Category(String[] categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}

public static Category getMyCategoryFromExternalCategory(String externalCategory) {

    Objects.requireNonNull(externalCategory);

    externalCategory = externalCategory.toUpperCase();

    {
        String[] categories = MY_CATEGORY_A.categories;

        if (Arrays.asList(categories).contains(externalCategory)) return MY_CATEGORY_A;
    }

    {
        String[] categories = MY_CATEGORY_B.categories;

        if (Arrays.asList(categories).contains(externalCategory)) return MY_CATEGORY_B;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no such suitable category");
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(getMyCategoryFromExternalCategory("category_a1"));

}
```